# Getting ClassCastException while running

Tags: java, android, classcastexception, android-sharedpreferences

This is my code for preference.xml

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="3"
        android:key="number"
        android:numeric="integer"
        android:summary="Enter how many Days older files"
        android:title="Set Days" />
```

and when i am trying to get its value with sharedpreference as below

```
int fileolderthan = sharedPreferences.getInt("number",7);
```

Getting error on running code java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer.

How to fix it, any tip please.

Comment: default values are always strings, even if the type is integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
int fileolderthan = sharedPreferences.getInt("number",7);
```

with

```
int fileolderthan = Integer.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getString("number","7"));
```

EditTextPreference saves value as string even if you set `android:numeric="integer"`. So you first retrieve the string, then convert it into integer.